# Why is my AD user-deletion script such a memory hog?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have another script that moved terminated users into the "Terminated" OU in Active Directory. It adds a note in the description, and the current day-of-year into the "Company" field.  Then this script looks in that OU for anything more than 60 days old and deletes the AD account, and also removes some of their associated folders on other servers.

It tends to run verrrrry slow and max out the memory while it's running.  Can anyone see any reason this would be happening?  Maybe it's not the most efficient way to do this?

Thanks in advance for any help!

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory  

$users = Get-ADUser -SearchBase "ou=Terminated,dc=domain,dc=com" -Properties "company", "description" -Filter * | where {$_.description -like "Terminated*" }
$Date = Get-Date
$Today = $Date.DayOfYear
$CSVDate = Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd
$TermList = @()

foreach($user in $users)
{
$DN = $user.DistinguishedName
$Homefolder = ("\\v12-dfs-home\homefolders$\" + $user.samaccountname)
$Profile = ("\\v12-dfs-pro\XA65Profiles\" + $user.samaccountname)
$Desktop = ("\\v12-dfs-home\desktops\" + $user.samaccountname)
$Term = $user.company
$Result = ($Today - $Term)
$altResult = ($Today + 365) - $Term

    If ($Result -gt 60)
        {
            $TermList += $user | %{Get-ADUser $_.DistinguishedName -properties displayName, employeeID, samaccountname, title, Description | select displayName, employeeID, samaccountname, title, Description}
            Remove-ADUser -Identity $DN -Confirm:$false
            Remove-Item $Homefolder -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Confirm:$false
            Remove-Item $Profile -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Confirm:$false
            Remove-Item $Desktop -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Confirm:$false
        }
    ElseIf ($Result -lt 0)
        {
            If ($altResult -gt 60)
                {
                    $TermList += $user | %{Get-ADUser $_.DistinguishedName -properties displayName, employeeID, samaccountname, title, Description | select displayName, employeeID, samaccountname, title, Description}
                    Remove-ADUser -Identity $DN -Confirm:$false
                    Remove-Item $Homefolder -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Confirm:$false
                    Remove-Item $Profile -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Confirm:$false
                    Remove-Item $Desktop -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Confirm:$false
                }
        }

}


# Output CSV of accounts being deleted
$TermList | Export-Csv c:\Results\Deleted_$CSVDate.csv -NoType
```

Comment: How many users could be in the terminated OU at any given time? Would it be the file deletion portions that are taking time? Be my guess

Comment: @Matt  There is typically somewhere between 100-200 users in the Terminated OU, and when the script searches for ones more than 60 days old it typically comes back with about 15-30 or so.  It could be the file deletion part taking time, but would that also eat up all the memory on the server I'm running the script on?

Comment: Don't build arrays. Get objects and pass to `ForEach-Object` to process each one. Another way to say this is to take advantage of the pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be problematic for active directory to retreive big data. Be careful when  trying to :

- Retreive users info ( may use all the ram and fail the command if no more RAM available to store the data ( Example : [This article](https://dmitrysotnikov.wordpress.com/2007/07/24/optimize-powershell-performance-and-memory-consumption/))
- ForEach loop can consume lots of RAM, again, depending on how much data you process.

I may be wrong but those are the only two things in your code that may slow your script and consume your RAM.

Here are some best practices

The ideal PowerShell script:

- Does not keep the whole set of objects but processes them one by one upon retrieval.
- Retrieves only the attributes it needs.
- Filters objects during retrieval.